# Data in loop from belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have house with apartments (belongs_to house). The summary shows the house with the apartments with some info as short description and price range. The code i have is this(works fine)

```
- house.appartments.each do |a|
  %li
    %a.main_img
    = link_to image_tag(a.attachments.first.file.url(:thumb), :height=>"93px", :width=>"135px", :class => "box"), apartment_path(a)
    %br/
    = link_to "#{a.name}", apartment_path(a), :class => "link_homepage"
    Description: #{a.short_desc}
    Price range: #{a.price_range}
```

I added a new model price with belongs_to relation to apartment. In this model/db the prices/rents data is stored of the apartments.

Question - Instead of a.price_range (apartment db-table) i want the data from the new price model/db-table in the summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a model named something like `House` which has an association with `Apartment` which then has an association to a new model you made called something like `ModelPrice`? If so...

I assume in your new table `ModelPrice` you have a column for `apartment_id` or whatever the apartment ID column would be named in order to setup the association to the `Apartment` model.

Can you do `a.model_price.price`?

Of course, the names of each object would change based on the actual names of your new model/table name and the price column that is within it.

Comment: when implement a.price.low_season_price i got the message "undefined method `low_season_price'. When i do a.price the object is found but i can't show the attributes...

Comment: In your `a.price.low_season_price` is `price` a model or an attribute?

Comment: price is a model and low_season_price is the attr